# How to correctly adapt this POST resquest to plot.ly REST API?

Tags: api, post, ethernet, intel-galileo

I'm using Arduino Galileo to plot a graph on plot.ly using REST API. With this code

```
  client.println("POST /clientresp HTTP/1.1");
  //client.println("Host: 107.21.214.199");
  client.println("Host: plot.ly");
  client.println("User-Agent: Galileo/0.0.1");
  client.print("Content-Length: ");

  int content_length = 276 + username.length() + api_key.length() + temperaturesY.length() + timesX.length();
  client.println(content_length);
  client.println();
  client.print("version=2.3&origin=plot&platform=Galileo&un=");
  client.print(username);
  client.print("&key=");
  client.print(api_key);
  client.print("&args={\"x\":");
  client.print(timesX);
  client.print(",\"y\":");
  client.print(temperaturesY);
  client.print(",\"type\":\"scatter\",\"mode\":\"lines+markers\",\"visible\":true}&kwargs={\"filename\":\"galileo_temperature\",\"fileopt\":\"overwrite\",\"style\":{\"type\":\"line\"},\"layout\":{\"title\":\"Galileo CPU Temperature\"},\"world_readable\":true}");
  client.println();
```

I'm getting this error:

```
{"url": "", "message": "", "warning": "", "filename": "", "error": "Missing required POST parameters: platform un key origin args kwargs"}
```

How to adapt this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the code:

```
client.println("POST /clientresp HTTP/1.1");
client.println("Host: plot.ly");
client.println("User-Agent: Galileo/0.0.1");
```

Add the content-type header:

```
client.println("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

With it I was able to sucessfuly plot a chart

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do a POST request like:

```
POST /clientresp HTTP/1.1
Host: plotly.ly
User-Agent: Galileo/0.0.1
Content-Length: (needs to be calculated)

version=2.3&origin=plot&platform=Galileo&un=my_username&key=my_api_key&args={"x":[my_collected_x_values],"y":[my_collected_y_values],"type":"scatter","mode":"lines+markers","visible":true}&kwargs={"filename":"galileo_temperature","fileopt":"overwrite","style":{"type":"line"},"layout":{"title":"Galileo CPUTemperature"},"world_readable": true}
```

Now in your sketch:

```
#include <Ethernet.h>

byte mac[] = { 0xDA, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFA, 0xEA };
EthernetClient client;

String username = "MY_USERNAME";
String api_key = "MY_API_KEY";

String temperaturesY = "[10,20,30,40,50]";
String timesX = "[0,1,2,3,4]";


void plotChart(){
  if (!client.connect("plot.ly", 80)) {
    Serial.println("... Couldn\'t connect to plotly's REST servers... ");
    return;
  }
  Serial.println("Connected to plotly's REST servers");
  Serial.println("Sending HTTP Post to plotly");

  client.println("POST /clientresp HTTP/1.1");
  client.println("Host: plot.ly");
  client.println("User-Agent: Galileo/0.0.1");
  client.print("Content-Length: ");

  int content_length = 276 + username.length() + api_key.length() + temperaturesY.length() + timesX.length();
  client.println(content_length);
  client.println();
  client.print("version=2.3&origin=plot&platform=Galileo&un=");
  client.print(username);
  client.print("&key=");
  client.print(api_key);
  client.print("&args={\"x\":");
  client.print(timesX);
  client.print(",\"y\":");
  client.print(temperaturesY);
  client.print(",\"type\":\"scatter\",\"mode\":\"lines+markers\",\"visible\":true}&kwargs={\"filename\":\"galileo_temperature\",\"fileopt\":\"overwrite\",\"style\":{\"type\":\"line\"},\"layout\":{\"title\":\"Galileo CPU Temperature\"},\"world_readable\":true}");
  client.println();
  Serial.println("Request sent. Waiting response..");
}

void setup() { 
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Ethernet.begin(mac);
  delay(5000);
  plotChart();
}

void loop() {
  //If Plotly response
  if (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.print(c);
  }
  delay(1000);
}
```

And the response should be something like:

```
{"url": "http://plot.ly/~username/1", "message": "", "warning": "", "filename": ""}
```

If you open the retrieved url, you should find your chart there

Source: [Internet of Things with Intel Galileo](https://www.packtpub.com/hardware-and-creative/internet-things-intel-galileo) , Chapter 3, "Plotting Galileo CPU temperature"

Comment: Actually I'm following this exactly eBook but when I tried I got the error message. Can you ensure that this works? I've never used HTTP protocols or plotly API before

Comment: I've just run exactly this sketch and got `Missing required POST parameters: platform un key origin args kwargs"}HTTP/1.1 408 REQUEST_TIMEOUT` Could you help me please?

Comment: Ok, let me check it as soon as I get home

Comment: Miguel? Could you answer me? Plase

Comment: Hi Gabriel, sorry for this huge delay. I can confirm the error. Apparently there are some changes in the Plot.ly API.